# ASP.NET MVC SEO friendly URLs and Sitemap

Tags: google, sitemap, seo

I've created an ASP.NET MVC 3 application and generated sitemap.xml using some free online tools.
It contains the following URLs:

```
http://www.mydomain/
http://www.mydomain/About
http://www.mydomain/Portfolio
http://www.mydomain/Contact
http://www.mydomain/Sitemap
```

But when I uploaded sitemap.xml to Google Webmaster tools, I got these numbers:

```
URLs submitted: 5
URLs in web index: 1
```

Do I have to change http://www.mydomain/About to http://www.mydomain/About/ in order to get all URLs into the web index or..?

Answer (score 2):

Just submitting pages to Google in an XML sitemap does not guarantee inclusion. It merely tells them where the pages are and then Google decides when and if it will crawl and index them. So changing the URL to include a slash will have no bearing on those pages being added to the index.